# Estou com este erro no form_for undefined method equipment_index_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Estou tentando fazer um `form_for` para cadastrar um equipamento, mas sempre que vai para a view de criar o equipamento obtenho erro.

Model de equipment:

```
class Equipment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :orderequipments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :orders, through: :orderequipments
end
```

Controller:

```
def new
   @equipment = Equipment.new
 end

 def create
   @equipment = Equipment.new(equipment_params)
   if @equipment.save
     redirect_to equipments_path
   else
     render :new
   end
 end

 def equipment_params
   params.require(:equipment).permit(:name)
 end
```

E a view de new:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-form">
  <%= simple_form_for(@equipment) do |f| %>
    <div class="product-new text-center">Cadastro de Equipamento:</div>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :name, label: "Equipamento" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions text-center">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Enviar" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mas quando vai pra view de new sempre me aparece este erro:

```
NoMethodError in Equipments#new
Showing /home/eduardo/code/eduardototi/vegoorapp/app/views/equipments/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `equipment_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fac0c0d4480>:0x00007fac0c0e2b98>
Did you mean?  equipment_path
Extracted source (around line #3):

1 <div class="container">
2  <div class="container-form">
3  <%= simple_form_for(@equipment) do |f| %>
4    <div class="product-new text-center">Cadastro de Equipamento:</div>
5    <div class="form-inputs">
6      <%= f.input :name, label: "Equipamento" %>  

Rails.root: /home/eduardo/code/eduardototi/vegoorapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/equipments/new.html.erb:3
```

Alguem saberia me explicar porque este erro esta acontecendo?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o seu problema está no uso da palavra `"equipments"`. Se você abrir o console Rails execute `'equipment'.pluralize` você verá que o plural de `"equipment"` é `"equipment"`.

Então, eu faria uma pesquisa em seu projeto e substituiria qualquer instância de `"equipments"` por `"equipment"` e acredito que isso resolveria.